# Django rest framework migrating from 0.x to 2.1.9

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After resolving some of my troubles while converting from django-rest-framwork 0.3.2 to the lates 2.1.9 I cannot see to fix this one (which i agree with a blog of Reinout.... it's a real pain in the ...)

I had this code:

```
class ApiSomeInputView(View):
    form = ApiSomeForm
    permissions = (IsAuthenticated, )
    resource=SomeResource


    def get(self, request):
        """
        Handle GET requests.
        """
        return "Error: No GET request Possible, use post"

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        some_thing =   self.CONTENT['some_thing']
        # check if something exist:
        something = get_object_or_none(Something,some_field=int(some_thing))
        if not something:
            raise _404_SOMETHING_NOT_FOUND
        #Note exludes are set in SomeResource
        data = Serializer(depth=4).serialize(something)
        return Response(status.HTTP_200_OK, data)
```

Now I have followed the tutorial and saw how you can do this different (maybe even prettier). By using slug in the url.

However.... I want to keep things backward compatible for the client side software... so I want to have this without putting the value of the query in the url. The client side uses json data and ContentType json in the header of a post.

In the first version of django rest framwork, I even got a nice browsable form in which to fill in the values for this query

My question: how to get this done in the latest version?

I can't seem to get a form in the views.... where I can fill in values and use in the proces

maybe good to post what I have tried until sofar...

first I changed the ModelResource in a Serializer:

```
class SomethingSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Something
        #exclude = ('id',)
        depth = 4
```

and than the view changed in to:

```
class ApiSomeInputView(APIView):
    permissions = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        some_thing = request.DATA['some_thing']
        # check if something exist: .... well actually this above already does not work
        something = get_object_or_none(Something,some_field=int(some_thing))
        if not something:
            raise _404_SOMETHING_NOT_FOUND
        serializer = SomethingSerializer(something)
        return Response(status.HTTP_200_OK, serializer.data)
```

Note: Bases upon the accepted answer (by Tom Christie) I als put an answer in which I show how I got it working (in more detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're inheriting from `APIView`, the browseable API renderer has no way of knowing what serializer you want to use to present in the HTML, so it falls back to allowing you to post a plain JSON (or whatever) representation.

If you instead inherit from `GenericAPIView`, set the serializer using the `serializer_class` attribute, and get an instance of the serializer using the `get_serializer(...)` method - [see here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html), then the browseable API will use a form to display the user input.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer! I was hoping at an answer from you! i think the see here link should be: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#genericapiview ? Gonna try it right away...

Comment: I got it working with this answer, can you please have a look at my answer in which I converted your answer to the code.... because I still have the feeling I Am abusing the Serializer as a form....

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the answer of Tom Christie (which I'll accept as the answer). I got it working:

I made an extra serializer which defines the field(s) to be shown to fill in for the post and shown using the GenericAPIView... (correct me if I Am wrong Tom, just documenting it here for others... so better say it correct)

```
class SomethingSerializerForm(Serializer):
    some_thing = serializers.IntegerField()
```

And with this serializer and the other one I aready had.

And a view:

```
class ApiSomeInputView(GenericAPIView):
    permissions = (IsAuthenticated, )
    model = Something
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializerForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)
         if not serializer.is_valid():
             raise ParseError(detail="No valid values")
         some_thing = request.DATA['some_thing']
         something = get_object_or_none(Something,some_field=int(some_thing))
         if not something:
             raise Http404
         serializer = SomethingSerializer(something)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

Above is working, and exactly the same as before....

I still got the feeling I Am abusing the Serializer class as a Form.